# cartesian combinations for component variants

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, cartesian-product, flatmap

Let's say I have an object specifying inputs for a button component, and the possible values of that input.

```
const buttonVariants = {
  colorMode: ['on-dark','on-light'],
  size: ['small','medium','large']
};
```

How could I create a cartesian function to generate templates for all possible combinations of the variants? I'd like to be able to re-use this function for multiple components, so it's important to specify that I'd need this to work for `n` variants.

I'm hoping to achieve something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript) but where the output would be:

```
[
  '<button colorMode="on-dark" size="small">button</button>',
  '<button colorMode="on-dark" size="medium">button</button>',
  '<button colorMode="on-dark" size="large">button</button>',
  '<button colorMode="on-light" size="small">button</button>',
  '<button colorMode="on-light" size="medium">button</button>',
  '<button colorMode="on-light" size="large">button</button>'
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It seems like you could use the example you linked to, then map over it to generate the desired output.

Comment: How about you try a nested loop? For all color modes, loop over all sizes and produce the output you've included.

Comment: You can directly modify the example that you linked: [demo](http://jsbin.com/siwefuqina/1/edit?js,console) -- it doesn't take much to flatten those results into an array of strings.

Comment: why not take s/t like this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54343749/1447675

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by first creating a generic function to generate the Cartesian product of multiple arrays. This function will be useful for generating all possible combinations of the variants you have. Then, you can map these combinations to generate the desired button templates. Let's implement this in JavaScript:

```
function cartesianProduct(arrays) {
    return arrays.reduce((acc, currentValue) => 
        acc.flatMap(c => currentValue.map(value => [...c, value])), 
        [[]]);
}

function generateButtonTemplates(variants) {
    // Extract variant keys and their possible values
    const keys = Object.keys(variants);
    const values = keys.map(key => variants[key]);
    
    // Generate all combinations of variant values
    const combinations = cartesianProduct(values);
    
    // Map each combination to a button template
    return combinations.map(combination => {
        const attributes = combination.map((value, index) => `${keys[index]}="${value}"`).join(' ');
        return `<button ${attributes}>button</button>`;
    });
}

const buttonVariants = {
  colorMode: ['on-dark', 'on-light'],
  size: ['small', 'medium', 'large']
};

console.log(generateButtonTemplates(buttonVariants));
```

By running this code, you will get the output in the format you specified, allowing you to generate templates for all possible combinations of the variants.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Array::flatMap()` to map all color/size combinations:

```js
const buttonVariants = {
  colorMode: ['on-dark','on-light'],
  size: ['small','medium','large']
};

const buttons = buttonVariants.colorMode.flatMap(c => 
  buttonVariants.size.map(s => `<button colorMode="${c}" size="${s}">button</button>`)
);

console.log(buttons);
```